# VPN on laptop/PC monitoring

Tags: vpn

I work from home and use a VPN to connect to work.  Can my company tell which time I'm using my laptop and which time I am using my PC?  Is this something easy for them to check?  The VPN is through Citrix.

Comment: I don't think so.  They'd be able to see difference MAC addresses are connecting through the VPN, but they'd have to have a way of mapping them to Laptop vs. Desktop.  If work has provided the devices, and they've tracked them with serial numbers this might be possible.

Comment: They are my personal laptop and PC, so the only software on it from them is the VPN software.

Answer (score 1):

The VPN client can check your hardware, record asset information and provide that information to the VPN concentrator.  Often this is used to ensure you're patched, have antivirus and are using a corporate asset.  It sounds like your company isn't checking for corporate owned assets and is expecting you to use personal assets.  Although they won't flag you for connecting with a personal asset, they will be able to tell that you're using two different machines.

http://blogs.citrix.com/2013/12/10/netscaler-gateway-advanced-end-point-analysis/

If you have a legitmate business need to use both machines, ask them, else they might freak out when something else creates an indicator, e.g., you accidentally connect twice.

Comment: Thanks! If they can see that I'm using two different machines, can they tell when I'm logged on with my laptop and when I'm logged on with the PC?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything which can tell the difference between a laptop or desktop.  You could create such a check by looking for the presence of Wifi gear, battery information, etc.  Somebody who's an expert in Citrix VPNs would know if they developed an easy laptop/desktop check.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they can.

MAC Address have nothing to do with this, because they are only seen at the local network. As soon as you hit your default gateway, they are gone. The gateway for your VPN is tied to a virtual NIC, and a virtual generated MAC, but it does not matter.

They can get the information from the VPN client. The client can send hardware type, OS version, versions of installed software, and any other information that your company finds relevant.

Using this information they can surely tell when you are using the laptop and when you are using the PC.